# New versions are not publishable

Tags: publishing

I have 3 versions for an item. On selecting the item, there is message above the `Quick Info` section:

> If you publish now, the selected version will not be visible on the
>   Web site because it has been replaced by an older version. Version 2
>   will be published instead.

This item is not in workflow.

When I check the `Change Restrictions` option in the `Publish` tab, only versions 1 & 2 are checked and version 3 is unchecked.

So, I marked version 3 as publishable. The alert message is gone and the item can be published now.

But when new versions are created, I have to manually check them in 'Change Restrictions`. This never happened before.

Is this a bug or is there any config setting to make all versions publishable.

Comment: Please check if there is a custom logic written for Item version added item:versionAdded You can check this via ShowConfig.aspx - URL http://[sitecoreinstanceurl]/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx

Answer (score 5):

One of the reasons this could happen is if the `Hide version` checkbox is checked on the `__Standard Values` item of the template you're using.

Find `__Standard Values` and check publishing restrictions are set for that item or open  `__Standard Values` in Content Editor, find `Lifetime` section of the fields, and uncheck `Hide version` checkbox.

Comment: In my case, Hide version is already unchecked.

Comment: Any custom event handler on one of those events: `<event name="item:versionAdded"/>`, `<event name="item:versionAdded:remote"/>`, `<event name="item:versionAdding"/>`, `<event name="item:versionRemoved">`?

Comment: Thanks @MarekMusielak, This helped.